# USB drive encrypted with VeraCrypt on Windows doesn't automount on Ubuntu

Tags: usb, veracrypt

I encrypted using VeraCrypt on a Windows machine and the problem is that it doesn't auto mount and show up.

I used `lsusb` to find the device so it is showing up.

```
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 0781:5575 SanDisk Corp
```

How do I mount this and can I install VeraCrypt on my Ubuntu machine and un-encrypt it?

Comment: Please is this an Ubuntu question and you can easily install on Ubuntu and try!

Answer (score 1):

> Can I install veracrypt on my ubuntu machine and un-encrypt it?

Of course you can install VeraCrypt on Linux.

Download the Linux version archive from the official website, extract the installer and run it.

You can mount the USB drive manually?

Maybe the VeraCrypt auto mount function is only for mounting drives at the OS boot time.